# Google Play App Signing and signature level permission

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-signing

I try to use signature level permission to share data between two apps in secure way. Unfortunately even if i use the same `upload key` for signing in both apps the Google Play changes their signature after uploading to the store. Because of that, my apps can't communicate. 
How to sign in two apps with the same key/certificate if we use google play app signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, sharing the same upload key does not mean that the app signing key will be shared as well. However there is a way to do that when you first enroll in App Signing by Play: under the "Advanced" section in the enrollment card, there is an option to reuse the app signing key of another app already enrolled in App Signing.

You will need to create a new app however since there is today no way to change the app signing key.

This is documented on this [page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB) under "Opt in to app signing by Google Play" > "New apps".

Hope that helps,

Comment: What if the app is already published and available in the store signed in with `upload key` of the second app? Can i enroll in App Signing and change this key? What about updates? Probably i should enroll before publishing right?

Comment: Are both of your apps fully published with a user base? If at least one of them isn't, I would recommend creating another app since the app signing key cannot be changed. If that's not an option, I would reach out to the Play Console support to see if they can do anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

I've made some research and I would like to explain here how **Google Play App Signing** works and how to use it with signature level permission.

First of all if we use Google Play App Signing we actually use two keys to sign in our app. First is **Upload key** and second is **App signing key**. Both are generated in the same way from Android Studio and we can use Upload Key from the one app as App singing key for the other app.

App signing key is stored in Google Play and after uploading it we don't have access to it. We have possibility to upload it when we enrol to Google Play App Signing for existing app or it can be generated by Google Play for new app and then we don't have access to it at all. We can say that **App signing key** is actually the real key which we use for distributing app for our users.

The whole mechanism looks like this:

[image: Google Play app signing mechanism]

[Image source (Official app signing documentation)](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

As you can see on the image we use **Upload Key** to upload our app to Google Play and then Google Play removes our signature and is signing in our app with different key. It is useful because if we loose our upload key we will not loose possibility to upload our app (we can ask Google for using the new upload key). Moreover Google Play can now split our app into smaller parts and distribute it independently and every part will be signed in with our App Signing Key ([Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)). 
The disadvantage of this solution is that the app which we upload to the store has different signature that app which we download from Google Play. 
It is very problematic especially if we use signature level permission in our app. Moreover it is also problem when we want to upload our app to different store than Google Play.

By using signature level permission we can share data between two apps in secure way ([use case example](https://www.codementor.io/maker-abhi/share-data-between-your-android-apps-only-securely-a0pa8ea0j)) but there is one main condition - both apps have to have the same signature. 
Even if we use the same **Upload Key** it doesn't mean our apps will have the same signatures because the keys which are used by Google Play can be different. 
In practice it means that when you test release version of your app everything looks great but after uploading it to Google Play it doesn't work (this problem affects every feature which depends on app signature - facebook login, tamper-detection).

So, how to use the same key for two apps when we use Google Play App Signing? 
When we create new app in Google Play and try to create first release to production then Google Play will ask:

[image]
And then under advanced options we can find:

[image]

After that both apps will have the same signature for our users. 
Unfortunately if we will try to do it for app which is already published for our users (we can enrol to Google Play App Signing later) we don't have this option available and we can't use the same key.

What if we can't do it but we want to use secure data sharing between two apps? 
We can verify signature which is not the same manually and try to prevent attack from the inside of our app which provides data. It is not as secure as first solution but more secure than doing nothing :)